# Is it normal merging or looping tables that has 400K records took over 8 hour?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table that contains approximately 390 000 records. In this table one column type is oracle's sdo_geometry package and in this column there is a point which has X and Y coordinates. So, in my job there is a task given to me that is Intersect these point using SDO_RELATE function and find id's which only have more than three intersections among all of these records.
So if we have point1 point2 point3 ...pointN then point1 is checked all of remaining ...pointN. And point2 must be checked all of remaining after itself. I find two solution for that but both of them continue over eight hour and I must do that in mostly 30 minutes. Is there any paralel way of doing this or more faster way which is not reqired cartesion product or what? Because approximately 400K records become 160billion after cartesian product

**NOTE:if point1 intersects point2 and point3 then there is no need to check intersection between point2 and point3. Intersections are likely cumulative.
For to do that I also add a column that stores STATE, so if state is 1, don't iterate that row but STATE update process also consume lots of time and at the beginning of FOR LOOP, query runs only one time and don't see STATE UPDATES.**

My alternative codes are given below:

```
Merge Into ORAHANCROSSES C
Using (With D as (select T.*, ROWNUM RN from (select MI_PRINX, GEOLOC from ORAHAN order by MI_PRINX) T)
   Select aROW.MI_PRINX  aROW_MI_PRIX, 
          aROW.GEOLOC    aROW_GEOLOC,
          bROW.MI_PRINX  bROW_MI_PRIX, 
          bROW.GEOLOC    bROW_GEOLOC,
          SDO_GEOM.RELATE(aRow.geoloc,'anyinteract', bRow.Geoloc,0.02) RES
   From   D aROW,
          D bROW
   Where  aROW.RN < bROW.RN
   ) Q
 On    (C.ID_POINT1 = Q.aROW_MI_PRIX and C.ID_POINT2 = Q.bROW_MI_PRIX)
 When Not Matched Then
 Insert Values (Q.aROW_MI_PRIX, Q.bROW_MI_PRIX)
 Where Q.RES = 'TRUE';
```

Second one is:

```
declare
counter number(10);
control number(1);
dup number(10);
res varchar2(5);--TRUE or FALSE
BEGIN
counter :=0;
dup :=0;
control :=0;
FOR aRow IN (SELECT mip,startmi,mi_prinx,geoloc,state,rownum FROM ORAHAN where state=0)
 LOOP
  FOR bRow IN (SELECT mip,startmi,mi_prinx,geoloc,state,rownum FROM ORAHAN WHERE state=0 and mi_prinx!=aRow.mi_prinx)
   LOOP
    counter :=counter+1;
    BEGIN
     select SDO_GEOM.RELATE(aRow.geoloc,'anyinteract', bRow.Geoloc,0.02) into res from dual;
     if (res='TRUE')
      THEN 
        Insert INTO ORAHANCROSSES values (aRow.MI_PRINX,bRow.MI_PRINX);
        UPDATE ORAHAN SET STATE=1 where MI_PRINX=bRow.MI_PRINX; 
        control :=1;
        --dbms_output.put_line(' added');
     END IF;
     EXCEPTION
      WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX
        THEN
          dup := dup+1;
          --dbms_output.put_line('duplicate');
          --continue;
    END;
  END LOOP;
  IF(control =1)
    THEN
      UPDATE ORAHAN SET STATE=1 WHERE MI_PRINX=aRow.MI_PRINX;
  END IF;
  control :=0;
END LOOP;
dbms_output.put_line('duplicate: '||dup);
dbms_output.put_line('counter: '||counter);
--commit;
END ;
```

I execute boths but it take too long (in eight hours there still execution going.).

I have oracle-11g live server and pl/sql developer. (database are not in my local pc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize that SDO_GEOM_RELATE is old function and SDO_RELATE is new one. SDO_RELATE is very fast but in SDO_RELATE there is no buffer parameter. To give a parameter for object buffer we did something like below;

```
declare
BEGIN
for curs in (select * from ORAHAN t) loop
 for curs2 in (select *
               from ORAHAN t2
              where SDO_RELATE(t2.geoloc,SDO_GEOM.SDO_BUFFER(curs.geoloc,0.2,0.02,'UNIT=M') , 
              'mask=ANYINTERACT') = 'TRUE'
                and t2.mi_prinx <> curs.mi_prinx) loop                    
  Insert INTO ORAHANCROSSES
   values
   (curs.Mip, curs.Startmi, curs2.Mip, curs2.Startmi);
  commit;
 end loop;
end loop;
END;
```

Now entire iteration finishes in one hour.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following algorithm, which I just thought about and scribbled on paper (with 10 points having two insections, but summed up a lot faster than O(n)=n²):

1. Start iterating over your 400K points and find out the min/max X and Y coordinates
2. Iterate through your points again and create (in memory) a line from Xmin to Xmax at each Y coordinate
3. In the 3rd iteration, create (in memory) lines from yMin to yMax at each X
4. For each horizontal line, select those having 3+ points on it
5. Do the same for each vertical line
6. Now you have two, probably a lot smaller lists, for which you can check each horizontal line against the vertical lines, if they have the same 3 (or more) points on it

Comment: Right now I try a different algorithm and if it is not working i will try that you suggest. Thank you a lot for your help.